# How to insert value into table if NULL? - MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to insert into a column if the column value is not null.

I have my table:

```
create table clock(
    usr_id int,
    clock_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    clock_in date,
    clock_in_time time,
    clock_out date,
    clock_out_time time,
    FOREIGN KEY (usr_id)references df_user(usr_id),
    primary key(clock_id)
);
```

I am trying to grab the last entry of the table and checking whether or not it is null.

```
SET @lastEntry = (SELECT clock_id FROM clock WHERE clock_id=(SELECT max(clock_id) FROM clock));
SET @clock_value = (select clock_out from clock where clock.clock_id = @lastEntry);
```

If the last entries clock out column is NULL (@clock_value IS NULL) then insert into the table.

```
if @clock_value IS NULL THEN insert into clock (clock_out, clock_out_time) values (curdate(), curtime());
```

Can someone please tell me the correct way of doing this process? SQL is telling me that the query is wrong. Thanks all!

Comment: perhaps you could supply the error message from mySQL.

Comment: Seems you are making this harder then it needs to be, and more convoluted.  Why are you inserting another record into the same table, seem would be better to update the null value, no?  What if two user_ids clock in at the same time, who do you clock out.  I'm missing the logic behind selecting the last clock_id

Answer (score 0):

What you need seems to be an update clause.

```
update clock set clock_out=curdate(), clock_out_time=curtime() ;
```

or something like that. You cannot insert here, because when inserting you create new rows.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I ended up using an Update clause and it worked, however Now I am having trouble with the clock in. I want to make sure the last record in the table has been updated from its NULL value before adding in a new clock in record. I am trying to make a statement : "Insert into table clock(clock_out, etc) values(etc) IF @somevalue IS NOT NULL". Is this possible? I am not able to make any statement of this sort.

Comment: Please supply the error message you received when you wrote your attempted insert query. That might help me better grasp the problem. One bad guess I am making is that the insert migh be failing due to the 'integrity violation' constraint - I am seeing you have a foreign key reference here. So, hope you are using a usr_id value here which is also present in df_user table. If it is any other issue, please supply your query and error message.